# problem with cookies and login/logout with axios

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch, axios

I need to login from the browser using an axios request.
the problem is that the cookies are not being set somehow.

since I am making a call from a javascript file,
the path that shows up in the browser is something like this
file:///E:/coding/login-request.html

I am providing the token in the code and making the request
and I am even able to login and I can see the cookies being set.

the problem is that after I logout, the cookies for the token gets removed 
and then when I try to login again. I am unable to do so.

now, why is that happening  and how do I fix this?

```
 let url = 'https://loginfromhere.co/login';
    fetch(url, {
      method: "get" ,   
      mode:'no-cors',    
       redirect:'follow',
      headers:{

          'Authorization':'Bearer '+ 'mytokenhere',  

          },
          credentials:'include'

    }).then(function(response) {
         console.log('response : ',response);  

      window.location.href = 'https://loginfromhere.co/';
    } ).
    catch((err)=>{
      console.log('err is : ',err);
    });
```

please give some ideas.

the network requests are being made in this order
https://loginfromhere.co/login

and then
https://loginfromhere.co/

and then 
https://loginfromhere.co/welcome

this happens when the login is successfull
and in that case I see 2 cookies set in application tab
remember_token and session

but when login is unsuccessfull .i.e after a logout 
then I only see one cookie after the login attempt
and that is session.

the redirect still happens in the same order that I have shown above
but the difference is that it stays on https://loginfromhere.co/login
and doesnt go ahead to the welcome page.

please tell me how to fix this. I am going crazy trying to fix this.